# Open activity on button click in NavigationDrawer

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-studio

I have created project in Android Studio with Navigation Drawer Activity and I have successfully created it,On navigation drawer activity I have created 3 section, In 1st section I put Button and I want to setOnClickListener method on that button which lead to start new Activity (ex. "xyz.class") I have used code

`startActivity(new Intent(this,xyz.class));`

but "this" keyword is not working and gives me error.
So, I changed code like

`Context c;
startActivity(new Intent(c,xyz.class));`

which gives NullPointerException,

My Section1 code is

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.pratik.crm50.R;
import com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFloat;
public class Dashboard extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    View rootView;
    Context c;
    private ButtonFloat float_btn;
    private Button but;
    private Button btn;
    Context c;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        View v;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_layout,container, false);
        } else {
            v = super.onCreateView(inflater,container, savedInstanceState);
        }
      View vv=v.findViewById(R.id.button_simple);
        vv.setOnClickListener(this);
        return v;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       // Toast.makeText(c,"Float Button",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("ssas","sasafa");
        //startActivity(new Intent(c,xyz.class));
    }
```

}

and I can get successfully log `Log.e("ssas","sasafa")` on above code.
So how to do this?

Comment: Why are defining Context c two times?

Comment: use new Intent(getActivity(),xyz.class)

Answer (score 1):

Fragment does not extend `Context` while the `Intent` constructor expects the first parameter to be exactly that.

The `Context c` variable is redundant because a `Fragment` saves the parent activity by default.

You need to use the activity (class that extends `Context`) that the fragment is attached to:

```
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), xyz.class));
```

Answer (score 1):

You get a `NullPointerException`, because you´re never assining a value to `Context c`.
So as user3249477 also mentioned use the method `getActivity()` to assign a value to c like `c=getActivity();`
Or call it directly while starting the Intent. This would look like this: `startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),xyz.class));`